# Magento & Hubspot - Submitting Form on Success Page

Tags: php, magento, curl

I'm trying to submit a form to Hubspot on the success page of Magento. I confirmed already that the variable $str_post contains all of the info that's needed. Unfortunately, I can't determine why $response is empty. It seems like the CURL connection is not being made but I can't seem to determine why. Is there something I need to do to trigger the CURL connection other than just loading the page?

Please note I've removed the GUI/Form ID from the URL.

```
<?php
//Process a new form submission in HubSpot in order to create a new Contact.

$hubspotutk = $_COOKIE['hubspotutk'];  //grab the cookie from the visitors browser.
$ip_addr = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];  //IP address too.
$hs_context = array(
        'hutk' => $hubspotutk,
        'ipAddress' => $ip_addr,
        'pageUrl' => 'https://www.myfoodstorage.com/onestepcheckout/',
        'pageTitle' => 'MyFoodStorage.com Cart Checkout'
    );
$hs_context_json = json_encode($hs_context);

//Need to populate these varilables with values from the form.
$str_post = "firstname=" . urlencode($firstname)
        . "&lastname=" . urlencode($lastname)
        . "&email=" . urlencode($email)
        . "&phone=" . urlencode($telephone)
        . "&address=" . urlencode($street)
        . "&city=" . urlencode($city)
        . "&state=" . urlencode($region)
        . "&country=" . urlencode($country)
        . "&hs_context=" . urlencode($hs_context_json);  //Leave this one be :)

 //replace the values in this URL with your portal ID and your form GUID
$endpoint = 'https://forms.hubspot.com/uploads/form/v2/GUI-ID/FORM-ID';

$ch = @curl_init();
@curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
@curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $str_post);
@curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint);
@curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
@curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = @curl_exec($ch);  //Log the response from HubSpot as needed.
@curl_close($ch);
echo $response;

?>
```

Comment: First off I hope this is in the block and not in the template (.phtml) file. Second you have suppressed all error reporting with the @ symbol so you will never get an PHP errors. Third, take a look at curl_error(): http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php

Comment: In which file you have added this code? can you please share in detail ? I want  to do the same thing. I have contact form and need to submit in hubspot in magento 2 how to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A successful submission to the Forms API will return a 204 (No Content) response, so there would be nothing in the body of the response.  You can get the status code using curl_getinfo.

```
$response = @curl_exec($ch);  //Log the response from HubSpot as needed.
echo @curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
@curl_close($ch);
echo $response;
```